# Cannot add foreign key constraint in my DB

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

i dont know why i have this error while creating my database:

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CollegeDB`.`Eleve` (
 `idPersonne` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
 `dateNaissance` DATE NULL,
 `lieuNaissance` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`idPersonne`),
INDEX `fk_Eleve_Personne1_idx` (`idPersonne` ASC),
CONSTRAINT `fk_Eleve_Personne1`
FOREIGN KEY (`idPersonne`)
REFERENCES `CollegeDB`.`Personne` (`idPersonne`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB

SQL script execution finished: statements: 10 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

i have table Personne and two other tables that inherit from it: Eleve and Enseignant
in total i have 10 tables in my EER diagram workbench model, any idea? 
Many thanks

table Personne:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CollegeDB`.`Personne` (
 `idPersonne` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
 `nom` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
 `prenom` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
 `sexe` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
 `statut` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
 `rue` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
 `image` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
 `cp` INT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`idPersonne`),
INDEX `cp_idx` (`cp` ASC),
CONSTRAINT `cp`
FOREIGN KEY (`cp`)
REFERENCES `CollegeDB`.`Commune` (`cp`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = big5
PACK_KEYS = Default;
```

Comment: Can you share the definition of the `Personne` table please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an index on Personne.idPersonne.

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html :

> MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that
>   foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan.

Comment: in the table Eleve you will see that i have created an index on idPersonne as Personne.idPersonne is referenced.

Comment: You need an index on the referenced table (Personne). MySQL also requires an index on the referecing table (Eleve) but if such index doesn't exist it will create it automatically.